# Avoiding jQuery Mobile AJAX behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have been messing around with jQuery Mobile and working out the limits and natural behaviours.

I came across an issue where I am manually calling an ajax script to load html for a dynamic element, however in doing so it appears the native jQuery interface is causing a full page reload after the ajax call is complete.

Is there a function to explicitly deny this particular request from triggering this default state behaviour?

Here is the (simplified) JS code:

```
$(document).on('click','.cell',function() {
    var i = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    $('#element').html('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php?i='+i[1],
        success: function(data){
            $('#element').html(data);
        },
        error: function(er){
            alert(er.responseText);
        },          
    });
})
```

So when I click the .cell it loads as expected, but pretty much as soon as the element is filled with the response, the whole page refreshes.

For reference this whole module (.cell and #element) are within a native jquery mobile navbar window.  Not sure what else needs to be provided at this point but ask and you shall receive

I have tried adding the following to the cell elements, but not doing changing anything

```
 data-ajax="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  The page that it was calling had jquery mobile initialisation in it so it was in essence loading everything again.

THe work around for me was to switch off the autoinitialisation on the loaded page and call any required functionality manually after the element is filled/loaded